# Does a Magic Mouse let me use all the multitouch features of Lion?

Tags: macos, multi-touch, mission-control, launchpad

Does the magic mouse support all of the gestures that the magic trackpad supports, including but not limited to Launchpad and Mission Control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### NO

The Magic Mouse can open Mission Control with a double tap on the mouse's surface, but it does not provide a gesture to open Launchpad, a Lion only feature. However Launchpad can be launched with a Magic Trackpad with a four finger pinch.

Comment: When you say lion only feature, do you mean Magic trackpad only feature?

Comment: Launchpad didn't exist before Lion. So my logic is:

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your logic, for Mission Control didn't exist before Lion either...

Comment: Great, apparently comments can only be edited for 5 minutes and enter submits your comment. Basically I was going to say IF a MM allows use of all the multitouch features of Lion then it should have a gesture for Launchpad. However it doesn't therefore a MM doesn't allow use of all the multitouch features of Lion.